# IIS rewrite rule check for file in virtual directory

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, coldfusion, iis-7.5, virtual-directory

I have added a folder as a virtual directory to a site and need to check for file path under the virtual directory NOT requested directory.

If the file exists under the virtual directory then need to rewrite to a handler i.e,.

```
Site Physical Path: D:/MySite/
Virtual Directory Physical Path: D:/MySite2/

Virtual directory name: virtualDir

Request file path: D:/MySite/index.cfm
Check file path: D:/MySite2/index.cfm
```

I have added following rule:

```
<rule name="Invoke handler for virtual directory files" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="true" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="D:\MySite2{PATH_INFO}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/customHandler.cfm?path={PATH_INFO}&amp;queryString={UrlEncode:{QUERY_STRING}}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

This will work fine but the problem is that I have to hard code the virtual directory physical path and it would change based on environments.

Is there a way I can set a conditional( based on environments ) variable and use that in the rewrite rule OR can use some replace function in the conditions? Any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: Try looking into the `SCRIPT_NAME` and `PATH_TRANSLATED`  [server variables in IIS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602(v=vs.90).aspx).

A combination of these with regex might be what you're looking for?

Comment: @JamesCushing I think those variables will work if the URL contains the virtual directory name. In my case, I need to check the file under virtual directory irrespective of the URL.

Comment: Can you give a more detailed example? So far, then, I understand this as being: -- 1) Someone connects to your site (mapped to D:/MySite) -- 2) Regardless of what URL has been requested, you need to check a virtual dir (D:/MySite2) -- 3) You want to apply this generally (i.e. find file in _any_ virtual dir) ? If I'm missing your qn here please clarify

Comment: @JamesCushing 3) I want to apply this generally using the virtual directory name under the current site.

Comment: Right so just replacing D:\MySite2 with whatever the current site's virtual directory is? I'm not sure this is possible - you'd need IIS to know that you have a specific "fallback" virtual directory (which is what it seems like you're doing; "if file doesn't exist, but does exist in the virtual dir, then call the custom handler") but without knowing what virtual directory that is. You'd be looking for some sort of {MAIN_VIRTUAL_DIR} variable, which I don't think is feasible?